# How to append one table column records into second table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a two tables:

**Employee**:

```
EmployeeID    First Name  Last Name
------------------------------------
    1            ABC          XYZ        
    2            DEF          LMN
    3            GHI          OPQ
```

**Conversation**:

```
ConversationId   FromUser    ToUser
-----------------------------------
    11              1          2
    22              1          3
    33              2          1
    44              3          2
```

I want output as follows

```
ConversationId    FromUserId    ToUserId    FromUser    ToUser
---------------------------------------------------------------
     11              1             2          ABC         DEF
     22              1             3          ABC         GHI
     33              2             1          DEF         ABC
     44              3             2          GHI         DEF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN the Employee table twice, once for from user, and once for to user.

```
select c.*, fu.firstname, tu.firstname
from conversation c
join Employee fu on c.FromUser = fu.EmployeeID
join Employee tu on c.ToUser = tu.EmployeeID
```

Comment: thank you for your reply... @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT c.conversationId
    ,c.Fromuser AS FromUserId
    ,c.ToUser AS ToUserId
    ,frm.FirstName AS FromUser
    ,t.FirstName AS ToUser 
FROM conversation c
INNER JOIN employee frm ON c.fromuser = frm.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN employee t ON c.touser = t.EmployeeId
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @StackUser

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.* , B.FIRSTNAME FromUser , C.FIRSTNAME ToUser FROM 
conversation A LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE B ON 
A.FromUser =  B.EmployeeID    
LEFT JOIN        
EMPLOYEE C ON A.ToUser = B.EmployeeID
```

Comment: thank you for your reply Sir..@Anubrij Chandra